# 'this' inside each function in Prototype JS

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, this, each

I'm trying to find a div element with `example` selector that also has `active` selector as denoted in the code.

With Prototype JS `this` returns `windows.object` rather than an individual div itself.

How do I make `this` to refer to each div element so that I can play with it?

```
$$('.example').each(function() {
    if(this.hasClassName('active')) {
        this.previous().setStyle({border:'1px solid #999'})
    }
});
```

Comment: Uh, just use `$$('.example.active')`?

Comment: And don't use `this`, [but a simple function parameter](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/each/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/each/

To access the element, you don't need change the context (`this`) of the iterator function. The iterator function receives the item as the first argument. You just need to name the argument.

```
$$('.example').each(function(div) {
    if(div.hasClassName('active')) {
        div.previous().setStyle({border:'1px solid #999'})
    }
});
```

Also, you can remove the conditional by updating the CSS selector passed into `$$`:

```
$$('.example.active').each(function(activeDiv) {
    activeDiv.previous().setStyle({border:'1px solid #999'})
});
```

If you are interested in controlling the value of `this` inside of a function, check out `call`, `apply`, and `bind`.

Comment: when using `.each()` the 2nd parameter would be the context - so in this situation you would not have the use `bind()` but can pass `this` as parameter 2 into `.each()`